# How to know level of every child relative to main parent in django-mptt?

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I use `django-mptt` application in my project. Let me try to explain the problem.

**views.py:**

```
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
referrals = user_profile.get_descendants().filter(level__lte=profile.level + 3)
```

With the help of next code I show descendants of current user (only 3 level) and want to know level of every child relative to parent. In fact in database that user can have child with level more than 3.

In template user A has next tree with 3 level

```
user A
 user B (level 1)
  user C (level 2)
    user D (level 3)
```

In fact in dababase user A has tree more than 3 level as you see. In my case it's 5.

```
user A
 user B (level 1)
  user C (level 2)
    user D (level 3)
      user E (level 4)
        user F (level 5)
```

Now when user D open his page in template he see his own descendants:

```
user D
 user E
  user F
```

I want to know level of user E and F  relative to user D. How to make it?

I tried in **views.py**:

```
for referral in referrals:
   print(referral.level)
```

This code return me level 4 for user E and level 5 for to user F.

Comment: Well you can subtract `profile.level` from it. So `print(referral.level - profile.level)`.

Comment: Thank you! I just thought this problem might be solved differently. Can you post your answer (not like comment)? I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *relative* level, is the level of the `referral` *minus* the level of the "current" `userprofile`. We can thus use `referral.level - userprofile.level`.

If you however want to *annotate* all these objects with a `relative_level`, we can use Django's ORM:

```
from django.db.models import F

(user_profile.get_descendants()
             .filter(level__lte=profile.level + 3)
             .annotate(relative_level=F('level') - profile.level))
```

So then all the descendants will have an extra attribute `.relative_level` that will containt the relative level.